# Getting autofill chrome extension to work with React textarea

Tags: jquery, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a textarea with an onChange listener in React.

```
// Parent's HandleChange
handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const text = event.target.value;
    this.setState({chatValue: text});
}
// Inside Render
const { chatValue, handleChange } = this.props;
<textarea type="text" value={chatValue} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

There is a chrome extension that our users use that will listen for all textareas and input fields on the page. When the user types something like **'brb'** it will change it to **'be right back.'** by selecting the textarea with jQuery and changing the value directly.

I have tried intercepting the discrepancy between the value of the textarea and the state in the parent's **componentWillReceiveProps** function. However this prevents my other function which inserts macros into the textarea.

I have also tried firing off a new event with the textarea's dispatchEvent function, but React does not listen to native events-- they use synthetic events.

Thanks!